# Adding an Alias to a WHERE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, where-clause

I am trying to figure out how to add an alias to the states abbreviations.

Example:

QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHAPTER, COUNT(CHAPTER)AS MEMBERS
FROM Name
WHERE MEMBER_RECORD = '1'
AND COUNTRY in ('',' ','United States')
AND CHAPTER IN 
('AL',
'AK',
'AZ')
```

I want to add the full state name to AL, AK AND AZ.

Example:

```
AND CHAPTER IN 
('AL' AS 'ALABAMA',
'AK' AS 'ALASKA',
'AZ' AS 'ARIZONA')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN CHAPTER = 'AL' THEN 'ALABAMA'
            WHEN CHAPTER = 'AK' THEN 'ALASKA'
            WHEN CHAPTER = 'AZ' THEN 'ARIZONA'
        END AS CHAPTER, 
        COUNT(*) AS MEMBERS
FROM Name
WHERE MEMBER_RECORD = '1'
AND COUNTRY in ('',' ','United States')
AND CHAPTER IN ('AL','AK','AZ')
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN CHAPTER = 'AL' THEN 'ALABAMA'
            WHEN CHAPTER = 'AK' THEN 'ALASKA'
            WHEN CHAPTER = 'AZ' THEN 'ARIZONA'
         END;
```

But I recommend that you create an alias table and perform a `JOIN` with it:

```
SELECT  A.CHAPTERNAME, 
        COUNT(*) AS MEMBERS
FROM dbo.Name AS N
LEFT JOIN dbo.Aliases AS A
    ON N.CHAPTER = A.CHAPTER
WHERE MEMBER_RECORD = '1'
AND COUNTRY in ('',' ','United States')
AND CHAPTER IN ('AL','AK','AZ')
GROUP BY A.CHAPTERNAME;
```

Comment: This is more complex than what I expected. Thank you for answering my question. I would have never figured this out. I will use the JOIN instead of the other one.

Comment: @Lamak . . . Your first example does not require repeating the `case` in the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I might be missing something, but I fail to see why it doesn't

Comment: I think you killed the left with that group by.

Comment: @Lamak Test, you can just group by CHAPTER

Comment: @Frisbee it doesn't "kill" the `LEFT JOIN`, it will just group every chapter that doesn't exist in the alias table as `NULL`